# @State variable getting reset for no reason [ios 15 SwiftUI]

Tags: swiftui, state, reset

I am using a @State variable to store a tag of some navigation Links.
But in ios 15, I notice that whenever I go to background, the state variable is getting reset, which causes that when I go back into the app, the view get popped for no reason.

```
@State private var userNavigateSelection: String? = nil

NavigationLink(destination: TestView(), tag: TestTag, selection: $userNavigateSelection) { EmptyView() }
```

I used a onChange method to monitor the changing of "userNavigateSelection", everytime I go into background. "userNavigationSelection" will be changed to nil. I have no idea why.

Comment: Works find with simple replicated code - Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4. Probably the reason in different code - provided minimal reproducible example.

Comment: If you can provide a simple reproducible example it would help us investigate the problem. If you cant produce the problem then it is somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your view containing @State variable is removed from view hierarchy after coming back to foreground. Try moving this variable higher in hierarchy and pass to view containing NavigationLink with @Binding.
Check: https://www.ralfebert.com/swiftui/state-lifetime/

Comment: This problem still happen to me, as it the variable is changed once the app is in background. I changed the navigation link to fullscreen cover temporary fix this issue. I have no idea why.